# Serve file with google cloud storage, google compute engine and external website

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, shopify

I got a question regarding a upload, edit and serve setup.

I have a setup where my shopify website lets users upload images to a google cloud bucket with javascript. When the file is uploaded to the bucket it's send to a compute engine which edits the files and the file is then uploaded to another bucket. All this is done.

But now I want to serve the file to the user on my shopify website. I can't figure out a way to do this. Is it even possible with my current setup? My problem is how to identify the user-session which uploaded the file, so that I can serve the file back to that person.

I hope someone has knowledge about this and is willing to help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Every person that logs into a Shopify store gets a customer ID. You can use this for your uploads. Ensure images get manipulated with that ID in mind. Now, use an App Proxy that sends the same customer ID to your App. Your App can then use this ID to find the image previously uploaded, and you can return it to the shop. A very common pattern of Shopify use.

As for getting the customer ID, one way is to dump it using Liquid since you have {{ customer.id }} or you can sniff it out of the cookies Shopify stores for a user session. It exists, but you'll have to dig for it, I forget its exact code.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful.
I'm wondering though if there is a way to do this with out having the user log in? Do you know if Shopify has a session ID or similar stored in cookies?